Reproducing Kernels
I was reading these notes about the uniqueness of the R.K.H.S. (reproducing kernel Hilbert space).
https://members.cbio.mines-paristech.fr/~jvert/svn/kernelcourse/notes/uniquenessRKHS.pdf
I was just curious if the alternative proof of Theorem 2, point 1 (the most trivial one), is correct. This states:
Theorem 2, part 1: If a reproducing Kernel (r.k.) exists for a Hilbert space of functions $H$, then it is unique.
I was just thinking that this follows even more easily from the following general fact on Hilbert spaces.
Claim: If we have a Hilbert space $H$ and two vectors $g$, $g'$ such that $\langle f,g \rangle = \langle f,g' \rangle$ for every $f \in H$, then $g=g'$.
Proof: The hypothesis implies that $\langle g-g',f \rangle =0$ for every $f$, therefore $g-g'$ is orthogonal to every vector in $H$. If the $g-g'$ is not null, chose $f=g-g'$, so that $\langle g-g',f \rangle =\|g-g'\|^2 \ne 0$. Contradiction. $\square$
Suppose now that a Hilbert space of functions $H$ has two different reproducing kernels $K(x,y)$ and $K'(x,y)$. Then $K(x,\cdot) = K_x$ and $K'(x,\cdot) = K'_x$ are vectors in $H$ such that $\langle K_x,f \rangle = \langle K'_x,f \rangle =f(x)$ for every $f \in H$. Applying the claim we have $K_x=K'_x$, i.e., $K(x,y)=K'(x,y)$.
Is this alternative proof correct or am I missing something?

Your proof is correct. In fact, I like your argument more than the one in the PDF you linked.

Perfect thanks for the feedback!
